# Add input to the onclick event in react

Tags: javascript, reactjs, formik

I have a form made with formik, in which one of the information entered is the contact, however the user can have more than one contact.

I want to add a button that when clicking, new fields for entering more contacts appear.
I've tried some logic, but to no avail

```
const { getFieldProps, touched, errors, isValid, handleSubmit } = useFormik({
    initialValues: {
      phone_name: '',
      phone_ddd: '',
      phone_number: '',
      phone_observation: ''
    },
    onSubmit: (values, actions) => {
      saveOrganization({
        variables: {
          name: values.phone_name,
          ddd: values.phone_ddd,
          number: values.phone_number,
          observation: values.phone_observation,
        }
    })
})

return (
<TextField
  margin="dense"
  id="phone_name"
  label={<IntlMessages id="name" />}
  fullWidth
  {...getFieldProps("phone_name")}
/>
{touched.phone_name && errors.phone_name ? (
  <small>{errors.phone_name}</small>
) : null}
<InputMask
mask="99"
disabled={false}
maskChar=" "
{...getFieldProps("phone_ddd")}
>
{() =>
  <TextField
  label={<IntlMessages id='ddd' />}
  fullWidth
  {...getFieldProps("phone_ddd")}
  />
}
</InputMask>
{touched.phone_ddd && errors.phone_ddd ? (
  <small>{errors.phone_ddd}</small>
) : null}
<InputMask
mask="999999999"
disabled={false}
maskChar=" "
{...getFieldProps("phone_number")}
>
{() =>
<TextField
label={<IntlMessages id='number' />}
fullWidth
{...getFieldProps("phone_number")}
/>
}
</InputMask>
{touched.phone_number && errors.phone_number ? (
  <small>{errors.phone_number}</small>
) : null}
```

I want to add a button and new inputs appear

Comment: The idea should be to create the form based on the datastructure and then add the new contact to the datastructure.

Answer (score 3):

This is my approach. First I declare initialValues to have field 'contact' as array like this

```
useFormik({
    initialValues: {
      contact: [
        {
          name: "",
          age: "",
        },
      ],
    },
  });
```

Then I create a function for adding new field

```
const handleNewField = () => {
    formik.setFieldValue("contact", [
      ...formik.values.contact,
      { name: "", age: "" },
    ]);
  };
```

And in the render just map it out from array like this

```
<form onSubmit={formik.handleSubmit}>
    {formik.values.contact.map((contact, index) => (
        <div key={index}>
            <label>Name</label>
            <input {...formik.getFieldProps(`contact[${index}].name`)} />
            <label>Age</label>
            <input {...formik.getFieldProps(`contact[${index}].age`)} />
        </div>
    ))}
    <button type="submit">Submit</button>
    <button type="button" onClick={handleNewField}>
        New Field
    </button>
  </form>
```

I have try this and this is work just fine for me. If you have any question feel free to ask me I'll try my best to answer

---

**Final code look like this**

```
import React from "react";
import { useFormik } from "formik";

function App() {
  const formik = useFormik({
    initialValues: {
      contact: [
        {
          name: "",
          age: "",
        },
      ],
    },
    onSubmit: (values) => {
      console.log(values);
    },
  });

  const handleNewField = () => {
    formik.setFieldValue("contact", [
      ...formik.values.contact,
      { name: "", age: "" },
    ]);
  };

  return (
    <div>
      <form onSubmit={formik.handleSubmit}>
        {formik.values.contact.map((contact, index) => (
          <div key={index}>
            <label>Name</label>
            <input {...formik.getFieldProps(`contact[${index}].name`)} />
            <label>Age</label>
            <input {...formik.getFieldProps(`contact[${index}].age`)} />
          </div>
        ))}
        <button type="submit">Submit</button>
        <button type="button" onClick={handleNewField}>
          New Field
        </button>
      </form>
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```